# How to manipulate the number in a numpy matrix with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix of:

```
[[-1.97237165e-07 -5.66877976e-07 -1.76817787e-08]
 [-9.99999985e-02 -2.00000000e+00  1.35515141e-10]
 [ 2.00000000e+00 -9.99999994e-02  1.17191894e-11]
 [-4.71890031e-07 -1.35793390e-06 -3.00000043e-01]
 [ 1.26268486e-07  3.63211240e-07  1.13835451e-08]
 [ 3.65190517e-12  1.05662146e-11  3.21131576e-13]
 [-7.75649309e-10 -2.23013474e-09 -6.85228749e-11]
 [ 1.26267188e-07  3.63207304e-07  1.13833879e-08]
 [ 4.15597865e-10  1.21628022e-09  4.17112586e-11]
 [ 3.22232197e-08  9.28302819e-08  2.93705273e-09]]
```

and I want to turn all the numbers which are smaller than 1e-6 into 0 without hurting the precision of the output (keep the original way, like -9.99999985e-02 ) with numpy. What should I do?

I am a math undergraduate and I am working on a research project. I am currently stuck at this step.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is a `numpy` array already, just set the appropriate elements using indexing, assuming `arr` is your array:

```
arr[arr < 1e-6] = 0
```

`arr < 1e-6` returns an array with the same shape as `arr`, with `True` at the positions where the condition is fulfilled and `False` otherwise. This array is then used for selecting the appropriate elements of `arr` by indexing, and they are set to `0`.

If you continue to work with `numpy`, you should familiarize yourself with [the basics of indexing arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basics-indexing).